# I want to authenticate a pop up, that doesn't have a body and I am unable to find window handle for that

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

[This is the webpage which I am trying to automate but this page doesn't have any inspectable element, right click is not working anywhere except on edit text fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tijtM.png)

Things I have tried.
1: Mouse and keyboard action.
2: switchTo().activeElement();
3: Window handler.
4: Robot class.
5: Clicking by passing coordinates of the element.
6: Used alert.
7: Tried sikuli.
8: Username and Password cannot be send in url, tried that too.

None of the above is working I don't even know the kind of pop up it is, It is comming from browser or server end and i am using local host.

Comment: Script is not executing after the pop up appears. It just stops even if i am printing anything after get() command nothing is printed. So how the further code will execute, whatever I do it will not execute.

Comment: I tried sikuli but not working. Sikuli is working for other sites like google search, but not on the site on which i am working.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding user name and password in the URL itself like below

http://{{user name}}:{{password}}@domain.com

Comment: I am using local server and I think pop up is comming from server end as soon as page is opened.

Comment: And even my script stop executing after the page is loaded, it's stopped after get() method.

Answer (score 0):

While passing username and password in url, you have to convert the Special character in Password or username to URL encoding.

Like for @ code is %40
and # code is %23.